# How to customize showDatePicker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, customization, flutter-layout

I'm using the showDatePicker function in a project, I'm new in flutter so I'm having a hard time doing some things. I want to paint in red some specific days and disable them to show they are not available anymore, is there any way I can do it?

For example, how could I show that the 27th is no longer available?
[image: Print of DatePicker dialog]

Answer (score 0):

See clear explanation on how to mark days as `selectableDayPredicate` on showDatePicker

[How to disable list of specific date on flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647938/how-to-disable-list-of-specific-date-on-flutter)